# Django 1.10: Redirect to another view or url not working. django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

In Django 1.10, My redirect to other view via url or the viewname is not working.

The main urls.py file is as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('app1.urls')),
]
```

The urls.py file inside app1 is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'app1'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^details/$', views.details, name='details'),

]
```

The views.py for app1 is as below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.timezone import now
import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

    def home(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("redirected from home..................")
            url = reverse('details')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
            # return redirect('app1:details')
            # return redirect('/details/')
            # return redirect('details')
        print("Not redirected..................")
        return render(request, "app1/index.html", {})


    def details(request):
        print("Redirect OK inside details")
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return render(request, "app1/details.html", {
            'today': today,
            'now': now(),
            'email_text': request.POST.get('email_item', 'bla bla'),
        })
```

I tried all the options in the home view with the commented code like using both HttpResponseRedirect and redirect but not able to redirect to the details view.

I get the error:

```
    django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'details' with
 arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'request': <HttpRequest>}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Any suggestions would help:

Comment: I have written a test, to check the same. The details of the test are here: [https://dpaste.de/aYBV](https://dpaste.de/aYBV)

Comment: The Project directory is here [https://dpaste.de/kO0q](https://dpaste.de/kO0q) and the ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls' in settings/base.py

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you found a solution long ago, but I've struggled with this problem before and I came up with a simple solution that doesn't require you to create a view that exists solely to redirect you to another view. Hopefully it helps some people out who need this question answered still. In general, it goes like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', lambda request: redirect('my_redirect_url_name')),
    url(r'^my_redirect_url/$', views.redirect_view, name='my_redirect_url_name'))
]
```

I'm not sure why, but this does not work if you only pass `redirect()`; it must be contained within a function such as a `lambda` function.

If you want to do something as simple as redirect them to the login page you can use the `login_required` decorator or another a custom login lambda function:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = [
    url(
         r'^$', 
         login_required(lambda request: redirect('my_redirect_url_name'), 
                               redirect_field_name='my_login_url_name')
    ), 
    # this custom redirect function will behave like login_required()
    url(
        r'^$', 
        lambda request: redirect('my_redirect_url_name') if request.user and \
            request.user.is_authenticated() else redirect('my_login_url_name')
    ),
    url(r'^my_redirect_url/$', views.redirect_view, name='my_redirect_url_name')),
    url(r'^my_login_url/$', views.login_view, name='my_login_url_name'))
]
```

Specifically in answer to your question, I think this will give the redirect you want. This in `urls`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^$', 
        lambda request: redirect('index') if request.method == 'POST' else \ 
                        redirect('details'),
        name='home'
    ),
    url(r'^details/$', views.details, name='details'),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

With this added to `views`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "app1/index.html", {})
```

Just FYI, I have not tested this with a redirect using `if request.method == 'POST'`, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Note the working example within your own code.

By specifying the app name you need to use namespacing with reverse.

```
reverse('details')
```

should read

```
reverse('app1:details')
```

See the documentation over here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/

Comment: Still no success.Though the response code is 302, the redirection doesnot happen and the first line in details view: 'Redirect OK inside details' is not printed too.